# the previous state is not saved - React useatate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to save objects to an array, but I can't do it, the old state is deleted. I have two states in my component, from two different forms, the first form is just text and I get the data by "handleChange", but the second form is several objects that I want to store in an array that I get by "handleChangeArray".

```
const [formCompra, setFormCompra] = useState({
        name: '',
        lastName: '',
        items: []
});

const [restForm, setRestForm] = useState();

const handleChage = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setFormCompra({
            ...formCompra,
            [name]: value
        })
}
 
const handleChangeArray = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setRestForm({
            ...restForm,
            [name]: value
        })
}

const handleSubmit = () => {

        let newData = {
            name: formCompra.name,
            lastName: formCompra.lastName,
            items: [...formCompra.items, restForm] //probably the error is here
        }

        console.log(newData)

}
```

As I mention, it is not possible to save the data in the array, I appreciate any help.

Comment: You probably need to set an initial value for `restForm` for example `useState({})` or `useState([])`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here `items: [...formCompra.items, restForm]`.   `formCompra.items` is empty. `{name: ..., lastName: ..., rest: restForm}` makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current state to set a new value, keeping all other values:

```js
setState((current) => ({
  ...current,
  key: newValue
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue may be that spread syntax only shallow copies the array, so in

```
const handleSubmit = () => {

    let newData = {
        name: formCompra.name,
        lastName: formCompra.lastName,
        items: [...formCompra.items, restForm] //probably the error is here
    }
```

`items` is a copy of an array that points to all the original objects.
try

```
let newData = {
        name: formCompra.name,
        lastName: formCompra.lastName,
        items: [...formCompra.map(x=>{...x}), {...restForm}] //probably the error is here
    }
```